Why is $ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(xy)}{xy}$ defined while $\lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \frac{\sin(xyz)}{xyz}$ is not?
I've found an exercise that compares the following limits:
$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(xy)}{xy} \qquad\text{and}\qquad \lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \frac{\sin(xyz)}{xyz}$$
The solutions suggests the first limit exists and is equal to 1, whereas the latter limit does not exist.
My working is as follows:
From a one-variable approach, it is known that $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$. Thus, it is reasonable to suppose $ \lim_{\textbf{v} \to (0,0)} \frac{\sin||\textbf{v}||^2}{||\textbf{v}||^2}=1.$
It could be said by epsilon-delta further, that because $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$, given $\epsilon > 0$, we can find a $\delta > 0$ with $0 < \delta < 1$, such that $0 < |x| < \delta $ implies $|\frac{\sin(x)}{x} - 1| < \epsilon$. If $0 < ||\textbf{v}|| < \delta$, then $0 < ||\textbf{v}|| < \delta^2 < \delta$, and finally,
$|f(\textbf{v}) - 1| = |\frac{\sin||\textbf{v}||^2}{||\textbf{v}||^2}-1| < \epsilon$.
I feel comfortable with this logic for two variables, however I am interested in why the logic fails when introducing a third variable. I predict it is largely due to how the variables behave but if someone could provide me with some intuition as to how to spot this behavioural shenanigans I would greatly appreciate it; Thank you in advance!

Do you have a source for the exercise? I believe they both exist and are 1

Vector Calculus 6th Ed. by Marsden & Tromba. Chapter 2.2 Q11. First limit was (a), second was (b). In the solutions it reads:
(a): Compose f(x,y) = xy with g(t) = (sin t)/t for t =/ 0 and g(0) = 1.
(b): The limit does not exist.

Perhaps a screenshot of the textbook question and answer. Otherwise I think the textbook is in error

In the copy of the book I see (https://uuwaterloohome.files.wordpress.com/2020/04/jerrold-e.-marsden-anthony-tromba-vector-calculus.pdf) , on page 502 the answer to question 11 (b) of Section 2.2 is $0$. (The question is on page 103). Even this isn't correct.

This question is also a good chance to practice the multi-dimensional taylor expansion of $\sin(xyz)$, if you have reached that point in your studies yet, and you should find that $\sin(xyz) \sim xyz$ for small $x,y,z.$ Obviously that had to be true, because you can just define a new variable $t=xyz$.

In other words, the same argument given for the first function works for this one as well.

Thank you everybody for your time in responding! I'm glad I looked close enough to discover an error in the text.

The limit does exist though and it is $1$.
Let $\epsilon$ be arbitrarily small  and let $\delta$ be such that the inequality $|\frac{\sin(\delta')}{\delta'} -1|$ holds for all $\delta'\le \delta$. Assume WLOG that $\delta \le 1$. Then let $C_{\delta}$ be $\{(x,y,z); xyz \le \delta\}$. Then you can check that both:

$|1-\frac{\sin(xyz)}{xyz}| \le \epsilon$ for all $(x,y,z) \in C_{\delta}$.

$C_{\delta}$ contains all points $(x,y,z)$ such that the inequality $||(x,y,z)||_2 \le \delta$ holds [and points not so close to the origin but that does not matter, all we care is that $C_{\delta}$ contains everything around a neighborhood of $(0,0,0)$].


ETA: I should be a bit more precise. In the $2$-dimensional case as well as the $3$-dimentional case, we to stay within the domain of the function i.e., need all variables nonzero. We must assume $(x,y,z) \rightarrow (0,0,0)$ but all of $x,y,z$ nonzero, but this is also true for the $2$-dimensional case, we must assume $(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)$ but both of $(x,y)$ nonzero.

Thanks Mike, I appreciate you taking the time to reassure me of this point. That makes much more sense than the limit not existing !

Glad I could help! To elaborate on my point 2. in my answer above in case anyone wants that: $||(x,y,z)||_2 \le \delta \implies \max{x,y,z} \le \delta$ $\implies$ $xyz \le \delta^3 \le \delta$. [so I left extra room to spare]

I should have written $\max{|x|,|y|,|z|} \le \delta$ instead

By definition, we have $sin(t)=t-\frac{t^3}{3!}+\frac{t^5}{5!}-...$ and hence $sin(xyz)=xyz-\frac{(xyz)^3}{3!}+\frac{(xyz)^5}{5!}-...$
Therefore, when $(x,y,z)$ approaches to zero, the behavior of $\frac{sin(xyz)}{xyz} \approx 1 - \frac{(xyz)^2}{3!} + [\text{higher order terms}]$. The ratio limit exists and the residue converges to zero quadratically with the product $xyz$.
